# Disable spell-checking on HTML textfields

Tags: html, forms

Can I somehow disable spell-checking on HTML textfields (as seen in e.g. Safari)?

Answer (score 468, accepted):

**Update**: As suggested by a commenter (additional credit to [How can I disable the spell checker on text inputs on the iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3416867/how-can-i-disable-the-spell-checker-on-text-inputs-on-the-iphone)), use this to handle all desktop and mobile browsers.

```
<tag autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" spellcheck="false"/>
```

Original answer: Javascript cannot override user settings, so unless you use another mechanism other than textfields, this is not (or shouldn't be) possible.

Comment: why has this been accepted? it does not make sense because it can override the users settings if the browser allows it. see ms2ger's answer.

Comment: Just because it was the best answer at the time. I'm guessing Michiel hasn't gone back through and marked the other one as correct. That would be fine with me since it is a better answer.

Comment: Important to note browser compatibility -- Mobile Safari (iOS) doesn't honor the tag for instance -- http://www.wufoo.com/html5/attributes/17-spellcheck.html

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3416867/how-can-i-disable-the-spell-checker-on-text-inputs-on-the-iphone has the correct answer to this (`autocorrect="off"`) for Mobile Safari - `spellcheck=` doesn't work

Comment: should be autoComplete="off" autoCorrect="off" autoCapitalize="off" spellCheck="false"

Comment: html attributes are case insensitive

Answer (score 234):

Yes, use [`spellcheck="false"`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/spellcheck), as defined by [HTML5](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/interaction.html#spelling-and-grammar-checking), for example:

```
<textarea spellcheck="false">
    ...
</textarea>
```

Comment: MDN has a table showing the default value of spellcheck for different browsers and elements:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/spellcheck

Comment: I'm getting an error "Unknown DOM property spellcheck. Did you mean spellCheck?" Using `spellCheck` seems to satisfy it. Could just be a react-dom thing.

Comment: @Shanimal Yes, react uses camel-case for DOM attributes. See https://reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html

Answer (score 19):

For Grammarly you can use:

```
<textarea data-gramm="false" />
```

Answer (score 8):

An IFrame WILL "trigger" the spell checker (if it has content-editable set to true) just as a textfield, at least in Chrome.

Comment: +1 for "content-editable set to true" trick that 's the real trick

Answer (score 4):

### JavaScript-based solution:

The following code snippet disables spell checking on all `textarea` and `input[type=text]` elements:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('input[type=text], textarea').forEach(field => field.spellcheck = false);
```

**2023 Update**: [@Ms2ger's HTML version](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1245570/13376511) is better if you don't need JavaScript.

Comment: +1 Read [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) on MDN, it's very useful. They allow you to have much less code for small things like this

Answer (score 1):

While specifying *spellcheck="false"* in the < tag > will certainly disable that feature, it's handy to be able to toggle that functionality on and off as needed after the page has loaded. So here's a non-jQuery way to set the *spellcheck* attribute programmatically:

:

```
<textarea id="my-ta" spellcheck="whatever">abcd dcba</textarea>
```

:

```
function setSpellCheck( mode ) {
    var myTextArea = document.getElementById( "my-ta" )
        , myTextAreaValue = myTextArea.value
    ;
    myTextArea.value = '';
    myTextArea.setAttribute( "spellcheck", mode );
    myTextArea.value = myTextAreaValue;
    myTextArea.focus();
}
```

:

```
setSpellCheck( true );
setSpellCheck( 'false' );
```

The function argument may be either boolean or string.

No need to loop through the textarea contents, we just cut 'n paste what's there, and then set focus.

Tested in *blink* engines (Chrome(ium), Edge, etc.)

Comment: Why are you making the value be an empty string and then make it what is was before? You also do `myTextArea.spellCheck = mode` instead of setAttribute and it will convert it to string automatically.

Comment: Resetting the value triggers the dynamic spell checking.

Answer (score 0):

If you have created your HTML element dynamically, you'll want to disable the attribute via JS. There is a little trap however:

When setting `elem.contentEditable` you can use either the boolean `false` or the string `"false"`. But when you set `elem.spellcheck`, you can only use the boolean - for some reason. Your options are thus:

```
elem.spellcheck = false;
```

Or the option [Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64810105/6151750) provided in his answer:

```
elem.setAttribute("spellcheck", "false"); // Both string and boolean work here.
```