# Textarea spellcheck attribute XHTML Strict

Tags: textarea, spell-checking, xhtml-1.0-strict

I would like to turn off the built-in spellcheck functionality in certain browsers such as Firefox and Opera on a textarea that contains HTML embed code for visitors to copy and paste. This can be done with following attribute:

spellcheck="false"

However, this causes a validation error for XHTML Strict. Also, it doesn't work properly in Opera, because the spell checking returns after a user selects the embed code in the text area. Is there another method for turning off spell check functionality?

Answer (score 7):

`spellcheck="false"` is a part of [HTML5 specification](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/editing.html#spelling-and-grammar-checking). Don't you mind changing your doctype in appropriate way?

Another idea proposed in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/254712/disable-spell-checking-on-html-textfields) question is using third-party WYSIWYG editors that don't use textfield for user input.

Answer (score 1):

```
 $("#id").attr("spellcheck",false);
 $("#id").attr("spellcheck",true);
```