# How can I disable the spell checker on text inputs on the iPhone

Tags: html, mobile-safari, spell-checking

Sometimes the spell checker is unnecessary, captchas, usernames, emails, etc. Is there a way disable it on some text inputs/text areas?

Answer (score 79, accepted):

As noted by my buddy Jonathan Stark, you should be able to use attributes like autocorrect and autocomplete to achieve the effect you're looking for:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="My Field" name="myfield"
    autocapitalize="none" autocorrect="off" autocomplete="off" />
```

Just tested in OS4 and it's working.

**UPDATE:** As of iOS5 `on` and `off` values in `autocapitalize` have been deprecated. Use `none` to completely disable automatic capitalization.

Comment: Most of the time, I don't turn off autocomplete so that the user can still use the "save password" feature of their browser.

Answer (score 53):

There is a spell check attribute in HTML5:

```
<textarea spellcheck="false">
```

Re: http://blog.whatwg.org/the-road-to-html-5-spellchecking

Browser support is limited.