# How to disable text Correction and Capitalize in Twitter login page?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, twitter, oauth

How to disable text Correction and Capitalize in Twitter login page?

[image]

( https://twitter.com/oauth/authorize?oauth_token=*OAUTHTOKEN* )

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Auto correct for text fields is determined server side. Twitter would have to change their website for it to not auto correct. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3416867/how-can-i-disable-the-spell-checker-on-text-inputs-on-the-iphone%20%22%22) talks about how that is done on the server side.