# How to disable spell check for a contenteditable div in a UIWebView?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uiwebview, contenteditable

I have a contentEditable div in a UIWebView. I want to disable the spell check feature.

Is there any API in the UIWebView ?

Thanks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Please Check this. [How can I disable the spell checker on text inputs on the iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3416867/how-can-i-disable-the-spell-checker-on-text-inputs-on-the-iphone)

Comment: is there actually anyone who succeeded in disabling the checker for a **contentEditable** div? I see that this method works for text inputs, but I disagree with this answer. I think it's a bug (or yet unimplemented feature) of Safari mobile (as of iOS 6).

Comment: This doesn't work with safari mobile.Does Anyone has solved this using jQuery or javascript??

Comment: I down-voted this answer because the question was specifically about contenteditable elements and this answer is about inputs and textareas.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this?

```
<div autocorrect="false" contenteditable="true"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

For me this works:

```
<div autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" contenteditable="true" />
```