# IOS5 UiWebview text input, dismiss autocorrect suggestion, can't enter text

Tags: ios

I have a text input in UIWebView. IF the auto correct suggests a correction, and i dismiss that suggestion, the text input is no longer accepting keyboard inputs.

If i switch to an different input, and back, then i can input text again.

Are there some sort of events being sent by the keyboard that can be used to address this?
Why do

Comment: “Why do” ? It seems part of your question is missing.

Answer (score 0):

You can't handle keyboard events for textfields inside an UIWebView, but you can disable autocorrect feature as mentioned here: [Disable autocorrect](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3428413/454165)