# UIWebView shows word suggest menu when user touches a word

Tags: iphone, ios, uiwebview, autosuggest

I am making a rich text editor app. When app started, UIWebView loads a html file which contains a content editable div. 
When I touch a word, UIWebView shows a menu suggest some words instead of selected word. How can I turn off this menu?

That's what I say:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xu4A9.png

This is my code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    webText=nil;
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"index" ofType:@"html"];
    [self.editor loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path]]];
    self.editor.delegate=self;    

    [super viewDidLoad];
}

-(BOOL)canPerformAction:(SEL)action withSender:(id)sender
{
    if (action == @selector(defineSelection:))
    {
        return NO;
    }
    else if (action == @selector(translateSelection:))
    {
        return NO;
    }
    else if (action == @selector(copy:))
    {
        return NO;
    }

    return [super canPerformAction:action withSender:sender];
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3416867/how-can-i-disable-the-spell-checker-on-text-inputs-on-the-iphone test this

Comment: @Arbitur I already tested it and not working.. I use a contenteditable div. Not a input or textarea.

Comment: Try the 2nd answer. Change the div to textarea

Comment: @Arbitur If I change div to textarea how can I use "document.execCommand" for rich text editing?

Comment: Im sorry but then i dont know.

Answer (score 0):

Here you have to return **NO** for all the specific methods the menu controller performs.

```
-(BOOL)canPerformAction:(SEL)action withSender:(id)sender 
{
    if (action == @selector(defineSelection:))
    {
        return NO;
    }
    else if (action == @selector(translateSelection:))
    {
        return NO; 
    }
    else if (action == @selector(copy:))
    {
        return NO;
    }

    return [super canPerformAction:action withSender:sender];
}
```

Hope this helps .

Comment: Have you set the delegates ?