# Turn off Chrome/Safari spell checking by HTML/css

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, spell-checking

Is there a way **for a web developer** to turn off Chrome/Safari/WebKit's spellchecking on particular `input` or `textarea` elements? I mean either by special tag attribute or a proprietary CSS instruction.

There is a CSS instruction for turning off outlining of `input`s so I thought that might also exist. I know how a user can do it.

Or, as a user, can I disable it for some particular domain?

Comment: Exact duplicate of [Disable spell-checking on HTML textfields](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/254712/disable-spell-checking-on-html-textfields), for ~5 years. Guess moderators were busy closing more legit questions.

Answer (score 225, accepted):

Yes, there is the HTML5 spellcheck attribute.

`<textarea spellcheck="false">` or `<input type="text" spellcheck="false">`

http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/editing.html#spelling-and-grammar-checking

Update: This is now supported in the latest versions of all browsers.

Comment: It doesn't seem to work on Safari Mobile. I have a input that I want to disable spell check and the iPad keeps on bringing spelling suggestions even though the attribute spellcheck is set to FALSE. :(

Comment: Did not do it in chrome android 67 :/

Answer (score 41):

This works in Safari 7.1 and should work also in others:

```
<input autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" 
spellcheck="false"/>
```

Only `spellcheck="false"` didn't work.

Comment: For iOS Safari, this is the way to go.

Comment: This is the only answer I've found that works in Chrome.

Answer (score 8):

for all elements of a form it is possible and so:

```
<form spellcheck="false" .. />
```

Answer (score 5):

In React, you gotta use `spellCheck` instead.

```js
<input spellCheck={false} type="text"/>
```

Answer (score 3):

Regarding outlining of input tags: don't do it, it's a visual cue for users.

But if you must:

```
#your-input{outline:none;}
```

Comment: If you are getting rid of the outline it's usually because you already have other visual cues in place for `:focus` and the outline is interfering with them; leaving the `:focus` as default causes discontinuity between different browsers. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/71074/how-to-remove-firefoxs-dotted-outline-on-buttons-as-well-as-links/ may also be helpful in this case.

Comment: @Hawken I've seen several sites remove visual cues and not provide any replacement. I'm ok with custom cues, but there has to be some.

Comment: The question is about the squiggly line inside the textbox when spell check deems the input misspelled, not the outlining, if I'm not mistaken. That said, your answer is good-to-know info.