# How to do spell checking in ZK textbox or textarea

Tags: spell-checking, zk

I am using Zk6.5.2 in my web application ,any one know if ZK provide any spell checking tool for textbox or textarea or we can integrate any third party tool .
Thanks

Comment: I do not have a solution, but I would try to use a js spell check if this should be a user feature so you have no traffic and the server usually do not have to know about spell checking.

Comment: @NabilA. my 2 cents are that a spell checker would need a large dictionary for **every language** (vocabulary & grammar) and that the size of this data should be considered before making the client/server decision

Comment: @NabilA Can we integrate http://www.javascriptspellcheck.com/JQuery_SpellCheck_Plugin this plugin with ZK Web pplication

Comment: @SeanConnolly in use cases I know, you need one or two languages and dict's are 150 to 500kb and can be cached. And the question is spell check not grammar check, so I do not think about grammar, but I don't think grammar files would be much bigger.
To subodh you can integrate every js lib in zk.

Answer (score 0):

Spell checking is usually handled by the browser.

On Chrome, you won't find spell checking on the normal `textbox` which gets rendered as `<input type='text'/>` but will see spell checking on the large `textbox` which gets rendered as `<textarea>`.
[@BalusC summed this up here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5986813/1906491)
Each of the browsers may have their own quirks like this, but you should be expecting to **depend on the browser's spell checker and not roll your own**.

If you're using the `<ckeditor/>` for input, you'll want to have a look at [their documentation](http://docs.cksource.com/CKEditor_3.x/Users_Guide/Spell_Checking) (note this is the 'User Documentation', there is no 'Developer Documentation' for spell check at this time.
Native spellchecking doesn't appear to be supported by all browsers at this time (Firefox & Safari only it seems) but you can enable [SCAYT (Spell Check As You Type)](http://www.webspellchecker.net/) with a bit of Googling. It's free but ad-based.

Comment: thanks but i will want to add a spell check as well in my product its customer needs so i was looking to integrate it for my application

Answer (score 0):

I have integrated [Rapid Spell checker](http://zkframeworkhint.blogspot.in/2013/06/integration-of-rapid-spell-checker-with.html)  with ZK framework