# Disable spell checker on forms

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, backbone.js

I have a Backbone app which accepts user entry and posts it to the DOM. Initial entries can be spelled however, but in Chrome when an existing DOM element (an entry's definition) is edited spelling errors are enforced and remain even once the field is no longer editable.

```
  this.$('.definition').attr('contenteditable', true).focus();
```

Comment: Not sure I'm fully understanding, but this might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4524000/turn-off-chrome-safari-spell-checking-by-html-css

Comment: that's exactly it.  thank you