# Disable spell check in SWT Browser widget

Tags: java, eclipse, browser, swt

I'm working on an Eclipse based application in which we use a `Browser` widget.
When typing text in this widget, a spell check is executed. We would like to deactivate it.

Is it possible ?

Comment: It will help if you mention the OS and the browser (and its version).

Comment: It's an 'org.eclipse.swt.browser.Browser' widget running a XULRunner that is embedded in an Eclipse 3.4 application on Windows.

Answer (score 1):

If you have control over the page that is displayed, you can simply disable spell checking by setting the appropriate attribute(s) (see 
[Disable spell-checking on HTML textfields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/254712/disable-spell-checking-on-html-textfields)). But I think you wouldn't have asked if that was the case...

If however the page is loaded from elsewhere you need to let the browser widget execute Javascript code that disables spell checking after the page is fully loaded.

The snippet below uses a `ProgressListener` to that is called when the page has been loaded completely. The Javascript that then gets executed is off the top of my head and may need refinement.

```java
Browser browser = new Browser( parent, SWT.NONE );
browser.addProgressListener( new ProgressAdapter() {
  public void completed( ProgressEvent event ) {
    browser.execute( "document.getElementsByTagName( 'html' )[ 0 ].spellcheck = false;" );
  }
} );
browser.setUrl( ... );
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not working on this project anymore but it looks like a very decent solution.