# Add to dictionary - prevent autocorrection within Microsoft's bot framework

Tags: node.js, botframework

Is there a way to prevent autocorrection within [Microsoft's bot framework's Web Chat](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out that autocomplete/autocorrect/spellcheck/etc. are browser features and are completely independent of webchat.

This worked for me:

```
<script>
  var textbox = document.querySelector('.wc-textbox')

  textbox.setAttribute('autocomplete', 'off')
  textbox.setAttribute('autocorrect', 'off')
  textbox.setAttribute('autocapitalize', 'off')
  textbox.setAttribute('spellcheck', 'false') 
</script>
```

[Disable spell-checking on HTML textfields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/254712/disable-spell-checking-on-html-textfields)