# How to remove red dotted line under text when using html contenteditable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using contenteditable on p tag and once I edit the text or click on it, a red dotted line appears at the bottom of the text. Can you please help me out to hide it using css. It shouldn't appear at all. On focus I am doing outline and border none.I am attaching image also.

[image]

Comment: That looks like spell checking.

Comment: This answer may help too :https://stackoverflow.com/a/254716/2159528

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette and mplungjan Thank you to both of you. It worked. :)