# Disable spellcheck on all material-ui components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

Is there a way to globally disable spellcheck on `material-ui` components?

Prior to using the `material-ui` library, I had used the following snippet to disable spellcheck on all newly-created DOM elements:

```
const disableSpellCheck = function(mutations) 
{
    const mutationCount = mutations.length;

    for (let i = 0; i < mutationCount; i++) {
        const mutation = mutations[i];
        if (mutation.attributeName === "spellcheck") {
            const addedNodes = mutation.addedNodes;
            const nodeCount = addedNodes.length;

            for (let n = 0; n < nodeCount; n++) {
                addedNodes[n].setAttribute("spellcheck", "false");
            }
        }
    }
}

const observer = new MutationObserver(disableSpellCheck);

observer.observe(document.getElementById('root'), {
    childList: true, 
    subtree: true,
    attributes: true, 
    attributeFilter: ['spellcheck']
});
```

This does not seem to work with components within `material-ui`. Because it is essential that spellcheck be disabled app-wide, I'm looking for a solution that does not involve modifying the style of each component individually.

Comment: try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/254712/disable-spell-checking-on-html-textfields

Comment: This doesn't solve my problem

Answer (score 12):

In order to do that, `spellCheck` prop should be provided to inputs.

This can be done in Material UI with:

```
<Input inputProps={{ spellCheck: 'false' }}/>
```

Default props can be applied to all inputs with a theme:

```
const theme = createMuiTheme({
  props: {
    MuiInput: { inputProps: { spellCheck: 'false' } }
  }
});

...

<MuiThemeProvider theme={theme}>...</MuiThemeProvider>
```